# AWS API Gateway HTTP API Parameter Mapping with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

Does the AWS Terraform provider support Parameter Mapping for API Gateway V2 HTTP APIs? Specifically I want to overwrite the path of an incoming request before forwarding it to a private integration. I can't seem to find a resource that allows me to specify parameter mapping under the `aws_apigatewayv2` Terraform AWS provider resources.

I'm after the Terraform that would allow me set up the equivalent of setting up the below via the Console.

[image: Equivalent from the AWS Console]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is set through [request_parameters](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/apigatewayv2_integration#request_parameters).

To check its form, you can first create it using AWS console, and then run AWS CLI

```
aws  apigatewayv2 get-integration  --api-id <id> --integration-id <id>
```

This returns (in my test) an output which shows `RequestParameters` as set in AWS console:

```
{
    "ConnectionType": "INTERNET",
    "IntegrationId": "rvy1o1c",
    "IntegrationMethod": "ANY",
    "IntegrationType": "HTTP_PROXY",
    "IntegrationUri": "https://www.example.com/path/parts",
    "PayloadFormatVersion": "1.0",
    "RequestParameters": {
        "overwrite:path": "newpath"
    },
    "TimeoutInMillis": 30000
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and good tip for getting the format. I was thrown off because the terraform documentation says `RequestParameters` is only used by Websocket APIs